# Find element from external style resource and then, change its own style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Just out of curiosity. Take this example case:

First, in my code-behind, I create three checkboxes and three ellipses:

```
for (int = 0; i < 3; i++){
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("MyCheckBoxStyle");
    checkBox.Name = "checkBox_" + i;

    Path ellipsePath = new Path();
    ellipsePath.Fill = Brushes.Gray;

    EllipseGeometry ellipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();
    ellipseGeometry.Center = new Point(0, 0);
    ellipseGeometry.RadiusX = 2.5;
    ellipseGeometry.RadiusY = 2.5;

    ellipsePath.Data = ellipseGeometry;
    ellipsePath.Name = "ellipse_" + i;
}
```

Now from the CheckBox style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"> 
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Green"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Green"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                <!-- Assumming the checkbox I'm checking is called "checkBox_1" I want to
                be able to find the ellipse path whose name is "ellipse_1" and change
                its style (for example, its color) -->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The idea is that each checkbox is associated with one ellipse. Like the comment says, assumming the checkbox I'm checking is called `checkBox_1`, I want to be able to find the ellipse element which name is `ellipse_1` and change its style (for example, its color).

Is this possible?

**Edit**

From your answers I see I can do it if both checkbox and ellipse belong to the same template. The problem I found (sorry, I forgot to mention it) is that currently I'm using a grid, where one of the rows contains the ellipses and another row contains the checkboxes, which are created at runtime (that's the reason I was using code-behind):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataTemplate like shown below as the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Path x:Name="path" Fill="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="2.5" RadiusY="2.5"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=checkBox, Path=IsChecked}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I find it a good idea. However, I have added details to my question. If I create the ellipses and checkboxes at runtime, that means I should create, for example, three `ItemsControls` from code-behind, but the style of those `ItemsControls` defined as a style resource?

Comment: No, you should not create any UI elements in code behind. Instead, you may create a view model item class and bind the elements in the DataTemplate to the properties of the item class.